# Nwjs how to use evalNWBinModule in another created window?

Tags: nwjs, nwjs-contexts

In the main window I write the following code and it works:

```js
nw.Window.get(null).evalNWBinModule(null, "./my.bin", "./my.js");
import("./my.js");
```

but if I create a new window via `nw.Window.open(MyOtherURL);` where I then move this code, then after running I get an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier
> './my.js'

what is the launch difference and what else do i need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

`nw.Window.get()` returns a reference to the Window itself, so you can then chain off of it.

`nw.Window.open()`, does not, but it does have a callback function gives you access to the new window, which you can chain off of.

```js
const url = 'page2.html';
const options = {};
nw.Window.open(url, options, function (win) {
  win.evalNWBinModule(null, './my.bin', './my.js');
});
```

However I'm not sure that will do what you want. You will likely be better off having the code run in your `page2.html` file directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that too, calling then `import("./my.js");` in page2.html, and using `nw.Window.get(null).evalNWBinModule` in page2.html (after all, `nw.Window.get(null)` returns a reference to its own window), but the error is the same. It seems that evalNWBinModule only works on the first window created when the application starts. There may be a reason why this is happening. In the meantime, I continue to experiment.